Identify horror movie with four aliens attacking a small town
Summary:

English language movie set in rural America. Saw it in the 80's, but could be a 70's movie. Had a B-movie vibe to it.
Alien spaceship crashes in the woods next to a small town. The aliens start attacking the townspeople. As always, local police is useless. Mysterious out-of-towner comes to the rescue.
First alien is an insectoid type. Hard exo-skeleton is impervious to bullets. Hero kills it with sonic waves.
Second alien is a Big Foot type monster. Not entirely sure how this guy was killed, but vaguely remember that involved getting shot with a shotgun of some sort.
Third alien is a reptilian who created mirror images of himself so the hero couldn't kill him. Eventually, the hero finds his hiding place and kills him.
Final twist (SPOILER)

* is that the hero himself is one of the aliens, and shows his real form to one of the towns people. A police man walks in, misunderstands and shoot the hero, killing him.



You're looking for the 1976 B-movie The Alien Factor. From an online synopsis:

It's set in a small American town and opens with a stereotypical sci-fi/horror movie scene: a young couple are drinking and making out in a parked car in the middle of nowhere and are suddenly attacked by a monster which kills one of them and leaves the other in shock. Turns out an alien spacecraft has crashed nearby, freeing the three ferocious zoological specimens that were on board. Now said beasts are roaming the countryside, killing random rubes. The local police (all two of them) are stumped until a mysterious expert arrives in town to investigate a supposed meteor crash, and ends up helping hunt down and dispose of the alien monsters.

The 3 aliens are a giant insect-looking thing, a big hairy creature and a reptile which uses holograms. And the mysterious 'expert' turns out to be an alien in the end. Here's the trailer:




Yes that's it! Thank you.
